# Racket - Match Function

Tags: match, racket

I'm learning how to use the "match" function in Racket but I'm not really sure how it can work in certain contexts.

For example, a problem I have is to use match to replace every occurrence of lambda in a program with the word "lumbda".

```
    > (lambda->lumbda '(lambda (lambda) lambda)) 
    (lumbda (lambda) lambda)
```

It should only change the function "lambda" to "lumbda", not any variables. I have no clue how to go about this.

Comment: It'll be useful if you post your attempted solution

Comment: Note that your example looks suspicious. Since it's quoted it will **never** become a procedure, just look like the source for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (lambda->lumbda exp)
  (match exp
    [(list 'lambda args body) (list 'lumbda args body)]
    [_ (error "unknown expression")]))
```

For example:

```
(lambda->lumbda '(lambda (lambda) lambda)) 
=> (lumbda (lambda) lambda)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I came up with the above solution but it is specified to use match.

Comment: Awesome! It works beautifully except in the case I just try and run

        >(lambda->lumbda 'x)

which should just return x. I'm just so unfamiliar with match it doesn't make too much sense. :/

Comment: Change the las line, instead of raising an error return the same expression that was passed as parameter

Comment: This doesn't do any sort of recursion. For example (lambda (x) (lambda (y) x)) will become (lumbda (x) (lambda (y) x)).

Comment: @AlexQueen Instead of the last match just do `[expr expr]` so that anything that is not matched by the first term is returned as is.  I would have used `list*` instead of `list`. How it's now `(lambda)` and `(lambda x y z)` are not matched.